# В чем разница между Thread и Runnable?

Tags: java

В чем разница между Thread и Thread (Runnable)?

Иными словами, какой плюс от того, что поток Thread будет реализован через интерфейс Runnable? Это типа поток в потоке или какие-то доп. функции будут? К примеру, доступ к UI?..

Comment: Runnable это просто интерфейс, который описывает класс с методом, он потоков не создает.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[@Futurama](/users/29860/futurama), в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28%29) совершенно четко прописан ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Читаем (жирный шрифт -- это выделено мной):

There are **two ways** to create a new thread of execution. **One is to declare a class to be a subclass of Thread**. This subclass **should override the run method of class Thread**. An instance of the subclass can then be allocated and started. For example, a thread that computes primes larger than a stated value could be written as follows:

```
     class PrimeThread extends Thread {
         long minPrime;
         PrimeThread(long minPrime) {
             this.minPrime = minPrime;
         }

         public void run() {
             // compute primes larger than minPrime
              . . .
         }
     }
```

The following code would then create a thread and start it running:

```
     PrimeThread p = new PrimeThread(143);
     p.start();
```

Суть в том, что мы переопределяем метод run класса Thread, который вызывается из метода start класса Thread, который мы и вызываем для запуска потока (исполнения нашей программы в новом потоке).

**The other way** to create a thread is to **declare a class that implements the Runnable interface**. That class then **implements the run method**. An instance of the class can then be allocated, passed as an argument when creating Thread, and started. The same example in this other style looks like the following:

```
     class PrimeRun implements Runnable {
         long minPrime;
         PrimeRun(long minPrime) {
             this.minPrime = minPrime;
         }

         public void run() {
             // compute primes larger than minPrime
              . . .
         }
     }
```

The following code would then create a thread and start it running:

```
     PrimeRun p = new PrimeRun(143);
     new Thread(p).start();
```

В принципе, как говориться -- "те же яйца, вид сбоку".

Если вдуматься, то суть та же. Создается (подготавливается к запуску) новый поток (класс Thread -- структура данных внутри JVM). В эту структуру заносится адрес функции (последовательности инструкций JVM), которая представляет программу, которую мы хотим выполнять в новом потоке. Вызов метода .start класса Thread (непосредственно или опосредовано, как унаследованного в первом случае) запустит новый поток (как именно -- зависит от ОС в которой работает конкретная JVM).

Вот собственно и все. Просто RTFM.

Answer (score 20):

1. Многопоточность в JAVA отнюдь не ограничена классом `Thread`
2. В контексте определённой задачи может быть выгоднее наследовать какой-то другой класс, но множественное наследование в JAVA не поддерживается, выход: `implements Runnable`
3. Интерфейс `Runnable` имеет посредственное отношение к потокам - его следует расценивать как передаваемую функцию, которая может быть выполнена где-то в другом месте (поток, очередь, класс, метод и т.п.)

Answer (score 17):

`Thread` - это абстракция над физическим потоком.

`Runnable` - это абстракция над выполняемой задачей.

Плюс использования `Runnable` состоит в том, что это позволяет логически отделить выполнение задачи от логики управления потоками.

Comment: Runnable не фигня, а интерфейс. А интерфейс для наследования. Похоже, вам никогда не приходилось иметь дело с ромбовидным наследованием.

Comment: @Futurama ну про тред вы поняли, значит язык человеческий. `Runnable` - это не фигня, а задача, которая может выполняться в потоке (в текущем или специально для этого созданном). Очевидно, что один поток может выполнять последовательно множество задач. А раз так, то нам нужно уметь отделять одно от другого, чтобы можно было этим управлять. Примеров на просторах сети можете нарыть множество.

Comment: @Futurama, ну-ка приведите пример выполнения задачи в `Thread` без использования `Runnable`.

Comment: @Futurama посудите сами, если мы знаем, что у нас есть тред и с ним уже ассоциирована задача, то было бы удобно иметь способ запуска задачи в этом треде. Ну конечно же тред не может выполнять задачи без Runnable в силу реализации (Thread implements Runnable) :)

Comment: @Futurama вы сами понимаете, что это код делает? Отвечаю: реализует интерфейс Runnable :)

Comment: @a_gura, 

  public Thread() {
        create(null, null, null, 0);
    }

    public Thread(Runnable runnable) {
        create(null, runnable, null, 0);
    }

Но ведь это совсем разные конструкторы. В первом случае нулевые параметры, а во втором с рунабле.

Comment: @a_gura,

public class Thread implements Runnable

Если изначальнго клас Thread реаилзует интерфейс Рунейбл, то зачем тогда использовать 

Thread(new Runnable)? если Thread() это одно и тоже получается

Comment: @Futurama причем здесь конструкторы? В вашем примере вы создаете анонимный класс с реализацией метода `run`, который является частью интерфейса `Runnable`.

Comment: @a_gura, тоесть это одно и тоже?

Comment: @a_gura пропущена буковка в "на физическим потоком"?

Comment: @ТимурВалиев Да, спасибо.

Answer (score 9):

`Runnable` - это интерфейс описывающий метод Run, с помощью которого Вы можете передать в другой класс свой код для выполнения. И он никак не связан с `Thread`, в том смысле, что он не несёт никакой скрытой функциональности. Для выполнения какого-то кода в потоке класс `Thread` просто использует этот интерфейс как уровень абстракции. Ничего не мешает Вам использовать `Runnable` любым другим способом. Например, для передачи коллбека.

`Thread` - это класс, который реализует поток и использует интерфейс `Runnable` для встраивания Вашего кода в поток.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд смысл в том , что множественное наследование в Ява возможен только от интерфейса и если вам нужно свой класс реализовать от какого то родителя то используете интерфейс Runnable . Если вам нравится и достаточно наследование от класса используете Thread .

Answer (score 4):

*В классе* **Thread** имеется несколько методов, которые можно переопределить в порожденном классе. Из них обязательному переопределению подлежит только метод **run()**. Этот же метод, безусловно, должен быть определен и при реализации *интерфейса* **Runnable**. Некоторые программирующие на *Java* считают, что создавать подкласс, порожденный от класса **Thread**, следует только в том случае, если нужно дополнить его новыми функциями. Так, если переопределять любые другие методы из класса **Thread** не нужно, то можно ограничиться только реализацией интерфейса **Runnable**. Кроме того, реализация интерфейса **Runnable** позволяет создаваемому потоку наследовать класс, отличающийся от **Thread**.