# выбрасывается NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, многопоточность

Почему выбрасывается `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?
В logcat написано, что ошибка происходит не в главном потоке(может я ошибаюсь), что противоречит названию ошибки

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

```
at com.agsdwee.agps.agps.SocketClient$ClientThread.run(SocketClient.java:47)
```

вызываю поток через `handler.postDelayed(new ClientThread(), 5000);` в конструкторе класса

Comment: `Handler` выполняет задачи в том потоке, в котором создан. А для того чтобы запустить новый поток не достаточно обозвать класс тредом)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Handler` выполняет задачи в том потоке, в котором он сам создан. 
Для того чтобы он выполнял задачи в другом потоке нужно этот поток подготовить и создать хэндлер в нём же (пример есть в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)), либо другой версией конструктора:

```
// создаём специальную версию потока, готовую из коробки к работе с Handler
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("my_socket_thread");
thread.start(); // запускаем поток
handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper()); // создаём хэндлер с привязкой к этому потоку
```

---

```
// дальше где-то используем
handler.postDelayed(new ClientThread(), 5000);
```

---

```
// и когда хэндлер больше не нужен (больше не будет использоваться)
// завершаем наш фоновый поток выходом из "петли"
handler.getLooper().quit();
```

P.S. Для ясности почему `ClientThread` не поток можно почитать ответы здесь:
[В чем разница между Thread и Runnable?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/399989/11515)

Answer (score 0):

Runnable выполняется в том потоке, который его вызвал. Так что у вас действительно выполняется запрос в основном потоке. Используйте AsyncTask

Comment: `AsyncTask` нынче не модно и под работу с сокетом он не очень-то подходит, иначе я бы просто ткнул носом в любой вопрос из колонки "Похожие" - там есть ответы куда информативнее и с примерами. Здесь можно просто стартовать обычный поток `new Thread(runnable).start()` или применить что-то более продвинутое.

Comment: Для человека который не особо опытен в многопоточных приложениях его более чем достаточно. Он обеспечивает вполне пригодную потокобезопасность сам по себе, а при старте отдельного потока ее надо обеспечивать самому. Потому я хоть и согласен что AsyncTask далеко не идеальный вариант, для тс я все же рекомендую начать именно с него