# Как правильно сделать Get запрос к серверу в android?

Tags: java, android, get

Всем привет!
Делаю приложение в котором нужно реализовать запрос на сервер и получить ответ в виде кода статуса 200 или же 403.
При пуске приложения ничего не происходи, не приходит ответ.

В чем может быть проблема?

Вот моя попытка:

```java
String s="https//.....com"

HttpURLConnection connection=null;
try{
    connection=(HttpURLConnection) new URL(s).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(2500);
    connection.setReadTimeout(2500);

    connection.connect();

    StringBuilder ab=new StringBuilder();

        if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK==connection.getResponseCode()){

            BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                ab.append(line);
                ab.append("\n");
            }
            Log.d("log1"," "+ab.toString());
        }
        else {
            Log.d("log2","!!!!");
        }

}
catch (Throwable cause){
    cause.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if(connection!=null){
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Данный код размещён внутри метода `onCreate()`

Comment: а где вы его делаете? 1) в основном потоке нельзя делать запросы. 2) нужно иметь разрешение

Comment: @МихаилРебров в методе onCreate()

Comment: так делать нельзя - вы тем самым блокируете поток, поэтому он и игнорируется.

Comment: Я давно не работал с Android. Раньше это делалось с помощью `AsyncTask`, но сейчас он помечен как устаревший. Нового решения я не знаю. С первым вариантом мог бы быстро набросать ответ, но он не актуален уже. Если никто не ответит раньше - то разберусь с новым способом и отвечу вечером.

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо, буду очень признателен!

Comment: Вот как вариант решения. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981606/184031 Но вообще лучше глубже изучить тему многопоточности в Андроид.